# ImmersiveResponse and Interactive Canvas

Tags: actions-on-google

I can hear a response. I just cannot see the new immersiveResponse, or basically the web app sample from Google.   Which I copied to my own web server.

The following is the JSON response output from the PHP script that is sent to the smart display

```
    {
     "payload": {
      "google": {
       "expectUserResponse": true,
       "richResponse": {
        "items": [
         {
          "simpleResponse": {
           "textToSpeech": "Hello, I am the AI voice test."
          }
         },
         {
          "ImmersiveResponse": {
           "loadImmersiveUrl": "https://mywebsite.com/webapps/index.html",
           "suppressMic": false,
           "updatedState": { "spin": false }
          }
         }
        ]
       }
      }
     }
    }
```

I was hoping to see the spinning triangle on my smart display.   If I go to a browser and use the loadImmersiveUrl link with the proper website instead of mywebsite.com, then I can see the web app run with a spinning triangle.   BTW, the mywebsite.com part was only changed for this post.

I used a PHP script to make a quick proto type, and it works, except no web app.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you updated your question with additional information such as: Have you tried it in the simulator and, if so, what happened? When you try it on the smart display, does it access your website to load the page? What happens on the smart display when you try it?

Comment: I did try it in the simulator, and it said "Hello, I am the AI voice test.".   I just don't see the web app run in the simulator or from my smart display when I run my test app.  I see the text on the display, just not the web app.

Comment: in the logs I am getting "MalformedResponse at expected_inputs[0].input_prompt.rich_initial_prompt.items[1].immersive_response: ImmersiveResponse is not supported on this device.".   Yet I tried it on a Lenovo Smart Display, a Pixel smart phone, LG smartphone, and the simulator.   All of them fail.   What gives?

Answer (score 0):

You have a capitalization typo in your response JSON. Instead of `"ImmersiveResponse"` it should have a lowercase-i:

```
     {
      "immersiveResponse": {
       "loadImmersiveUrl": "https://mywebsite.com/webapps/index.html",
       "suppressMic": false,
       "updatedState": { "spin": false }
      }
     }
```

Comment: Yeah, I meant to go back and edit that.   It's lowercase.   But it's still not working, and the logs still say  "MalformedResponse at expected_inputs[0].input_prompt.rich_initial_prompt.items[1].immersive_response: ImmersiveResponse is not supported on this device.".   The interactive canvas stuff is still in preview.   Have you got it working prisoner?   If so, then are you in the US?   I am in Canada, and I am beginning to wonder if the updates have been sent out to all my devices, so they can display and work with immersiveResponse.